# receiving local error tls no renegotiation with Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, mtls

I'm trying a new integration with a payment service. After billing information changes, I'm supposed to receive a callback from the payment service on my Azure Function. The service documentation says that their requests are signed with a certificate for **mutual tls authentication**.
But the webhook callbacks are not reaching my Azure Function. The support team of the service says that all their requests ended with this error **"local error: tls: no renegotiation"**.

For tests, I've made a function only to receive the request and send the content to an Azure Service Bus Queue:

```cs
[FunctionName("Callback")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get" , "post" , "put")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{   
  string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
 
  try
  {
    var objeto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(requestBody);
 
    ServiceBusClient client = new(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnectionString"));
    ServiceBusSender Sender = client.CreateSender(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("QueueName"));
 
    ServiceBusMessage message = new(objeto.ToString());
    await Sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    log.LogError(e, e.Message);
  }
 
  return new OkResult();
}
```

Then published the Azure Function and set Client certificate mode to **Require**.

The Function runs nice when I make a request from Postman, but the payment service provider gets tls: no renegotiation error.

I've made some search, but can't grasp what I need to do to receive the webhook request properly. Someone can point me what I'm missing?

Comment: TLS is sent before a Request is sent and establishes encryption.  The Request will never be sent if TLS fails.  The certificate has to be loaded on both client and server before TLS can be used. Error message I think indicate4s a proxy is being used and you may need to turn of proxy.  Your request should be HTTPS (not HTTP).

Comment: Thank you @jdweng for your time
I've followed https://hafizmohammed.medium.com/configuring-client-certificates-on-iis-95aef4174ddb and was able to make the request working!

Answer (score -2):

I've followed the steps in the below link and its working now:

https://hafizmohammed.medium.com/configuring-client-certificates-on-iis-95aef4174ddb

Comment: It would be better to add these steps to the answer if possible, as opposed to just providing a link. The link could be broken in the future. Thanks